# Splitting String based on this six characters 0102**

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How can I split a flat string based on `0102**`? string tokenizer is working for only `**`. Is there any way to split based on `0102**`? Please suggest

Here is my complete method

```
private String handleCibil(InterfaceRequestVO ifmReqDto, String szExtIntType) throws MalformedURLException, org.apache.axis.AxisFault, RemoteException {

    /* Declaration and initiliazation */
    ConfVO confvo = ifmReqDto.getExtConfVo();
    String szResponse = null;
    String cibilResponse = null;        
    String errorResponse = null;
    String endpointURL = null;
    long timeOut = confvo.getBurMgr().getBurInfo(szExtIntType).getTimeOut();
    endpointURL = formWebServiceURL(confvo, szExtIntType);
    URL url = new URL(endpointURL);



    log.debug("Input xml for cibil "+ifmReqDto.getIfmReqXML());
    BasicHttpStub stub= new BasicHttpStub(url,new org.apache.axis.client.Service());
   szResponse = stub.executeXMLString(ifmReqDto.getIfmReqXML());





    //szResponse=szResponse.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
     log.debug("szResponse "+szResponse);

    /* Validate if the obtained response is as expected by IFM */
    try {

        extDao = new ExtInterfaceXMLTransDAO(ifmReqDto.getSemCallNo(), ifmReqDto.getIdService());
        extDao.updateRqstRespXML10g(ifmReqDto.getInterfaceReqNum(), szResponse, GGIConstants.IFM_RESPONSE);

        //log.debug("CIBIL_RESPONSE_XPATH " + GGIConstants.CIBIL_RESPONSE_XPATH);
        Document xmlDocument = DocumentHelper.parseText(szResponse);
        String xPath = GGIConstants.RESPONSE_XPATH;
        List<Node> nodes = xmlDocument.selectNodes(xPath);
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            String keyValue = node.valueOf(GGIConstants.RESPONSE_XPATH_KEY);
           // log.debug("keyValue : " + keyValue);

            if (keyValue.equalsIgnoreCase(GGIConstants.RESPONSE_XPATH_KEY_VALUE)) {
             //   log.debug("node value  : " + node.getText());
                cibilResponse = node.getText();
            }
        }
        log.debug("cibilResponse " + cibilResponse);

        String errorResponseXPATH = GGIConstants.CIBIL_ERROR_RESPONSE_XPATH;
        List<Node> errorResponseNode = xmlDocument.selectNodes(errorResponseXPATH);
         for (Node node : errorResponseNode) {               
                errorResponse = node.getText();

        }
        log.debug("errorResponse " + errorResponse);

      if(cibilResponse!=null && cibilResponse.length()>0)
      {
           StringTokenizer cibilResponseResults = new StringTokenizer(cibilResponse,"**");

           String tempResponse="";
           ArrayList probableMatchList = new ArrayList();
            while (cibilResponseResults.hasMoreElements()) {

                tempResponse = (String) cibilResponseResults.nextElement();
                if(tempResponse.length()>=80)
                {   
                    String memberRefNo = tempResponse.substring(69, 80).replaceAll(" ", "");
                    log.debug("memberRefNo " + memberRefNo);

                    if (memberRefNo.length() > 0) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(memberRefNo) > 0) {
                            cibilResponse = tempResponse;
                            cibilResponse = cibilResponse+"**";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            probableMatchList.add(tempResponse+"**");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        probableMatchList.add(tempResponse+"**");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cibilResponse = tempResponse+"**";
                }
            }

            log.debug("After finding the Member reference number cibilResponse " + cibilResponse);
            log.debug("After finding the Probable reference list " + probableMatchList);
            // TKN 008 
        cibilResponse=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(cibilResponse).replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]","");
            ifmReqDto.setIfmTransformedResult(cibilResponse);
            ifmReqDto.setProbableMatchList(probableMatchList);    
      }   
       if (errorResponse!=null && errorResponse.length()>0) {
            throw new GenericInterfaceException(errorResponse
                    + " for the seq_request " + ifmReqDto.getSeqRequest() + " Seq_Interface_req is >> "
                    + ifmReqDto.getInterfaceReqNum(),
                    GGIConstants.SEND_REQUEST_CONSTANT + Strings.padStart(String.valueOf(ifmReqDto.getIdService()), 2, GGIConstants.DEFAULT_NUMBER_STRING)
                    + GGIConstants.CIBIL_ERROR_CODE);
        }
       else if (cibilResponse==null || StringUtils.isEmpty(cibilResponse) ) {
            throw new GenericInterfaceException("Cibil TUEF response is empty >> cibil Service "
                    + "for the seq_request " + ifmReqDto.getSeqRequest() + "Seq_Interface_req is >> "
                    + ifmReqDto.getInterfaceReqNum(),
                    GGIConstants.SEND_REQUEST_CONSTANT + Strings.padStart(String.valueOf(ifmReqDto.getIdService()), 2, GGIConstants.DEFAULT_NUMBER_STRING)
                    + GGIConstants.INTERFACE_ERROR_RESPONSE);
        }
            /* Setting Instinct response to ifmReqDto object */
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("SQLException while connecting to DataBase. Exception message is  ", e);
        throw new GenericInterfaceException("SQLException >> Instinct Service "
                + "for the seq_request " + ifmReqDto.getSeqRequest() + "Seq_Interface_req is >> "
                + ifmReqDto.getInterfaceReqNum(),
                GGIConstants.SEND_REQUEST_CONSTANT + Strings.padStart(String.valueOf(ifmReqDto.getIdService()), 2, GGIConstants.DEFAULT_NUMBER_STRING)
                + GGIConstants.DB_OPERATION_ERROR);
    } catch (GenericInterfaceException exp) {
        log.error("Exception occured while valid:", exp);
        throw exp;

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        log.error("Exception occured while valid:", exp);
        throw new GenericInterfaceException("GeneralException >> Instinct Service "
                + "for the seq_request " + ifmReqDto.getSeqRequest() + "Seq_Interface_req is >> "
                + ifmReqDto.getInterfaceReqNum(),
                GGIConstants.SEND_REQUEST_CONSTANT + Strings.padStart(String.valueOf(ifmReqDto.getIdService()), 2, GGIConstants.DEFAULT_NUMBER_STRING)
                + GGIConstants.UNKNOWN_ERROR);

    }
    return szResponse;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code with small example?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Posting examples of input and expected output could help us help you better.

Comment: It is huge flat string. Each flat string will have end characater as 0102**. If i use string tokenizer I am to split based on **. But my problem is double star(**) will come any where in the string. So i have to use (0102**).

Comment: @Karthik Don't post code in comments (it is hard to read). Instead [edit] your question and post it there.

Comment: I have posted my complete method.Please find string Tokenizer part where i am trying to split the response.. Thank you for all..It will be helpful to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I suspect that you forgot to escape `*` in split regex.

Try maybe

```
String[] resutl = yourString.split("0102\\*\\*");
```

---

In case you want `*` to represent any character then use `.` instead of `*`

```
String[] resutl = yourString.split("0102..");
```

---

In case you want `*` to represent any digit use `\\d` instead

```
String[] resutl = yourString.split("0102\\d\\d");
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it provides a really good reference to start with. The `.split` method uses a regex to split up a string based on a delimiter.

```
String[] tokens = myString.split("0102\\*\\*");
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. `*` is the regex for *"everything"*

Comment: You're right, you'd need to escape it to get a literal *.

Comment: Whether String tokenizer can be replaced in that method by split. ? I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "blabla0102**dada";
String[] parts = string.split("0102\\*\\*");
String part1 = parts[0]; // blabla
String part2 = parts[1]; // dada
```

Here we have a String: "blabla0102**dada", we call it string. Every String object has a method split(), using this we can split a string on anything we desire.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean literally split by "0102**"? Couldn't you use regex for that?

```
    String[] tokens = "My text 0102** hello!".split("0102\\*\\*");
    System.out.println(tokens[0]);
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);
```